# Ruby on Rails: how to create an object without switching the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am incredibly new to rails, so I think my questions is pretty simple. I essentially have an object submit button on a view page (so runs create and save for the specified object) but on selecting the button I don't want the view to change at all (so just stay with the same page that was already loaded). I'm having trouble editing the create action in my object controller so that nothing happens to the view (is this even possible? or is the idea that a new view must occur for every action).

Thanks for all your help!
Lisa

Comment: you don't want to show green or red messages after submitting form? Is that it?

Comment: Hi and welcome, it would probably help explain the question better and make it easier for someone to answer, if you could give a quick sample of the code you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating an action in the controller,

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

   def index
   end

   def youraction
   end
end
```

,then set a route to it in the routes.rb

and then simply set your form to point to that url and add the

```
remote: true
```

option to the form tag.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to store the object and you dont want the URL to change.

In your create action, after the object is saved. Redirect to that view.

so something like:

```
$   if @object.save
    redirect_to :action => "index"
    # or
    # redirect_to object_path # you can set this in config/routes.rb
    # or
    # redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @object.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using ajax request:

in your controller create an action that does the job of creating the object you want:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #this is your view controller
  end

  def youraction
    #create an object
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

and then bind your button with a javascript function that does the ajax request:

HTML

```
<button id="submit_button">Submit</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#submit_button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url_to_the_controller/youraction',
      type: 'POST'
      success: function (){
        alert('success');
      },
      error: function (){
        alert('error');
      }
    });
  });
}
```